# Can't add nginx latest version app repository in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

Ubuntu installs nginx 1.4.6 as default. I'm trying to install the lastest stable version of nginx (1.6.2). So [here](http://www.2daygeek.com/install-lemp-server-linux-nginx-mysql-php-in-linux-mint-17-ubuntu-14-04-debian-7-6/) it says:

> you need to add Ubuntu PPA repository to get latest stable version of
> Nginx on your system. use the below commands to do it.
>
> ```
> # Add repository to your system
> # magesh@magesh-desktop:~$ add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/$nginx
> ```

But when I try this command it throws error:

```
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:nginx/'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
```

How can I solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Replace `$nginx` with `stable` :

```
add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable
apt-get update
apt-get install nginx
```

Comment: @Alex Jolig, When i was adding PPA they build the repository like that. Updated the article as per Xavier Lucas advice. Thanks for notifying the error.

Comment: This worked for me to be able to add http2 to my nginx vhost config on Ubuntu 14.04. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the dir **/etc/apt/sources.list.d/** make file **nginx.list** with these lines:

```
deb http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ codename nginx
deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ codename nginx
```

Here *codename* is your Ubuntu version (Lucyd Lync, Hardy Heron, etc).

Also you must add PGP key in your store and update packages list:

```
http://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key
wget http://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key
apt-key add nginx_signinx.key
apt-get update
```

Now you can install latest stable version of nginx. All information from [nginx.org](http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html#stable).

Comment: Did that before asking the question. But didn't work